# Django social_auth custom user model FacebookBackend explanation

Tags: django, django-models, django-socialauth, django-facebook

I'm trying to use social_auth (omab) for the first time and I'm find that there is no working example how to store basic facebook user data. Authentication works and user is created without problem as it's explained in the social_auth docs but I need to store `gender` and `locale` also. Both of them belongs to the basic facebook user data so they are in the facebook response all the time.

I'm use Django 1.4, Python2.7 and latest social_auth. So I was try to use `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.UserProfile'` in settings.py file and model.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import signals
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from social_auth.signals import pre_update
from social_auth.backends.facebook import FacebookBackend


class CustomUserManager(models.Manager):
    def create_user(self, username, email):
        return self.model._default_manager.create(username=username)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    locale = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    #social_auth requirements
    username   = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    is_active  = models.BooleanField()

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/profiles/%s/' % self.id

    def facebook_extra_values(sender, user,response, details, **kwargs):     
        profile = user.get_profile()
        current_user = user 
        profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=current_user)

        profile.gender = response.get('gender')
        profile.locale = response.get('locale')
        profile.save()
        return True

    pre_update.connect(facebook_extra_values, sender=FacebookBackend, weak = False, dispatch_uid = 'facebook_extra_values_user')
```

In the settings.py I'm define pipeline

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    #'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
)
```

but with above I get error `AssertionError: ForeignKey(None) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'`

Also I was try to use `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'` instead as I was do before to extend user.model, which works well but don't understand how to populate needed data when UserProfile is created. Does anyone can place working code for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to archive it, what fits better to your project is up to you of course, here's a list of available options:

1. Define this setting `FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = ('gender', 'locale')`, the values will be available at the `UserSocialAuth` instance, to get them just do `user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook').extra_data['gender']` or `['locale']`. This is possible just because the information is available in the basic user data response.
2. Use a user profile to store this data (check [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) about it). Then just add a [pipeline entry](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) that stores the values in your profile instance.
3. Create a custom user model, `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'`, and again add a custom pipeline entry that stores the values in your user instance.

Number 1 is not the best solution IMO, since a user can have several Facebook accounts connected and it could create a mess. Number 2 is good for Django 1.4 and lower, but it's deprecated starting from Django 1.5, something to take into account. Number 3 is a bit messy IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't know how to do this, if I try 3rd solution. Custom user model is my UserProfile class but how to add pipeline to it.

Comment: In that case you have a profile model, so your solution is number 2. Check the docs about pipelines, but basically create a function similar to this one https://gist.github.com/3906521, that's assuming that your profile model has gender and locale fields.